# Sorting function for int column with only integers values not working when data loaded using ajax function in Datatables

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatables

Attached is the image of [ImageofDescOrder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Najg.png) how the sorting works in my case. I am doing sorting from the server-side that is the controller. It sorts the number of records in the lists and sends the JSON result to the view. However, the sorting function for CustomerCode with only integers values with "string" datatype is not working when data loaded using the ajax function in Datatables.

Below is my code for JS:

```
               var table = $('#tblLocks').DataTable({
               responsive: true,
               autoWidth: false,
               serverSide: true,
               processing: true,
        },
               url: "@Url.Action("LoadLocks", "Locks")",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                dataSrc: function (json) {
                        return json.data["LockCommonViewModels"];
                    }
                },
      columns: [    
                { data: "SerialNumber", name: "SerialNumber", autoWidth: true },
                { data: "CustomerName", name: "CustomerName", autoWidth: true },
                { data: "CustomerCode", name: "CustomerCode", autoWidth: true },
                { data: "ManufactureDate", name: "ManufactureDate", autoWidth: true },
        ],
order: [[3, "desc"]]
        });
```

HTML

```
                <table class="table display table-condensed table-striped table-hover locations-table" id="tblLocks">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LockCommonViewModels.First(x => true).SerialNumber)</th>
                        <th class="name">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LockCommonViewModels.First(x => true).CustomerName)</th>
                        <th class="">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LockCommonViewModels.First(x => true).CustomerCode)</th>
                        <th class="">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LockCommonViewModels.First(x => true).ManufactureDate)</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr></tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
```

Sorting from the server-side:

```
if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDir)))
            {
                if (sortColumnDir == "asc")
                {
                    switch (sortColumn)
                    {
                        case "SerialNumber":
                            lists = lists.OrderBy(o => o.SerialNumber).Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "CustomerName":
                            lists  = lists .OrderBy(o => o.Customer != null ? o.Customer.Name : o.SerialNumber).Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "CustomerCode":
                            lists = lists .OrderBy(o => o.Customer != null ? o.Customer.CustomerCode : o.SerialNumber).Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "ManufactureDate":
                            lists = lists .OrderBy(o => o.ManufactureDate).Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
                            break;
                       
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    switch (sortColumn)
                    {
                        case "SerialNumber":
                            lists = lists .OrderByDescending(o => o.SerialNumber).Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "CustomerName":
                            lists = lists .OrderByDescending(o => o.Customer != null ? o.Customer.Name : o.SerialNumber).Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "CustomerCode":
                            lists = lists .OrderByDescending(o => o.Customer != null ? o.Customer.CustomerCode : o.SerialNumber).Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "ManufactureDate":
                            lists = lists .OrderByDescending(o => o.ManufactureDate).Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What exactly is "not working"? It doesn't display? You get a console error?

Comment: If you're question is how to sort as a numeric field and specify the type of column then you can add **"type": "num"** to your columns definition.

Comment: @GlynnHurrell: There is no error in the console. I tried following ways:
1) **columnDefs: [
                { "type": "num", "targets": 2 }
            ],**
2) **{ data: "CustomerCode", name: "CustomerCode", autoWidth: true, "type":"num" },**

Neither works.

Comment: use something like postman or create an Ajax method in JS to check your endpoint and the JSON property names as you may find that the first letter of each property has been changed to lowercase e.g. **CustomerCode** becomes **cutomerCode**. That has caught me out a few times